# Convert from string array to char* const

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm looking for a way to call execvp() in a C++ program that uses string arrays. So if, for example, I have an array of strings,

```
s[0] = "ls";
s[1] = "-l";
```

then, `s[i].c_str()` converts it to `const char*`. However, I need `s[i]` converted to a `char* const` to pass it to [`execvp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). Is there any way to do this in C++?

Comment: and must be sure, that std::string pointer is taken, exist to the last moment of algorithm using pointer  (often error: pointer from variable on the stack)

Comment: or make copies of the strings

Comment: `const_cast` doesn't work for `const char*` to `char* const`. How will making copies of the string help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question. I had to convert the `const char*` to a `char*`.

However, since C++ doesn't allow conversion from `const char*` to `char*`, I had to create an `extern C` function. I converted the string `s` to a C-string (as a `const char*`), passed it to the `extern` C function. Within the C function I could then convert it from a `const char*` to a `char*` and subsequently pass it to `execvp()`.